# Three Dots jQuery on ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the ThreeDots jQuery pulgin and it works great.  I am having trouble using it on an ajax success event.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'url',
    success: function(value) {
        $("#content").append(value);
        $(".ellipsis").ThreeDots({max_rows:3});
    }
});
```

I load some new data and append the new data to a div (this works great).  When I call the ThreeDots function from inside the success event it takes about 1 minute to work and the browser is not responsive during this time.  There are .ellipsis spans returned in the new data.

Is there a better way to be doing this?  Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach?

### Update

@Nick,  Thanks for your answer.  I used this and I went one step further.  The above still reruns on every ellipsis in content not just the newly returned ellipsis results.

I now do this:

```
$(value).appendTo("#content").find('.ellipsis' + document.getElementById('hidPage').value).ThreeDots({max_rows:3});
$("#hidPage").val(($("#hidPage").val()-0) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the `.ThreeDots()` plugin *only* on the `.ellipsis` elements in the returned response, instead of re-running it on *all* of them, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'url',
    success: function(value) {
      $(value).appendTo("#content").find('.ellipsis').ThreeDots({max_rows:3});
    }
});
```

You can't chain it the reverse way because `.ThreeDots()` isn't chainable (it returns a custom object), but the above version should work fine.